# What's a good way to implement something similar to an interface in Python?

Tags: python, types, interface

What's a good way to implement something similar to a Delphi/C# interface or abstract class in Python? A class that will force all its subclasses to implement a particular set of methods?

Comment: Why not just make the base class with all the methods and just not overwrite them in the subclasses?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html Is this what you want ?

Comment: See also http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/abc/ for a good example of use

Comment: Similar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5856963/abstract-methods-in-python

Comment: Also see [Pythonic use of the isinstance function?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175277/175286#175286)

Comment: Can I ask why you want to do this, rather than duck typing?

Comment: "Can I ask why you want to do this". No... LOL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way to do this is to use the abstract base class implementation that has been included in Python since version 2.7.

This lets you mark a base class as abstract by using the `abc.ABCMeta` metaclass. You may then mark methods and properties as abstract. When you instantiate a class with the `ABCMeta` metaclass (or any of its subclasses) an exception will be thrown if any abstract properties or methods remain undefined in the instance.

e.g.

```
>>> from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
>>> class Foo(object):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    @abstractmethod
    def bar(self): pass


>>> class BadFoo(Foo):
    pass

>>> BadFoo()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#9>", line 1, in <module>
    BadFoo()
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class BadFoo with abstract methods bar
>>> class GoodFoo(Foo):
    def bar(self):
        return 42


>>> GoodFoo()
<__main__.GoodFoo object at 0x027354B0>
>>>
```

The check is done only when the class is instantiated because it is perfectly legitimate to have a subclass that only implements some of the abstract methods and is therefore itself an abstract class.