# Extract columns in 4 pickle files and join them together

Tags: python, concatenation, pickle

I am trying to get a single column from 4 separate pickle files and join them together.

`1.pkl` column "1"
`2.pkl` column "1"
`3.pkl` column "1"
`4.pkl` column "1"

I need a function that opens all files and extracts 1 column from all and combine them. I just can't figure out if it is in a list / series/ array which is making it difficult to write functions.

Comment: If you unpickle a file and then call `print()`  on what you get, you will be closer to knowing what sort of data structure you are dealing with.

Comment: You can also use a series of `try`/`except` blocks until one works. Look up "EAFP" and/or see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733992/determine-whether-a-key-is-present-in-a-dictionary/3734681#3734681) answer of mine on the topic.