# Dumping data with pickle

Tags: python, pickle

I am very confused about how to use `pickle`, I'm trying to make the computation a lot faster by storing the values that have been computed, and creating a pickle file for the ones computed. When a certain function hasn't been computed yet I want to open the pickle file and create a new input of the newly computed function. Here's my atttempt:

```
try:
    with open('EinsteinBbb.pickle','rb') as f:
        Bbb = pickle.load(f)
except:
    Bbb = dict()
def EinsteinBbb(nl, ll, nu, lu):

    global Bbb
    try:
        Bbbfile=pickle.load(open('EinsteinBbb.pickle','rb'))
    # Check if Bbb[(nl, ll, nu, lu)] needs to be computed
        if True: #TODO: replace with the correct condition
            print('Computing Bbb[{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}]'.format(nl, ll, nu, lu))
    except:   
        Bbb[(nl, ll, nu, lu)] = nl*ll*nu*lu
        with open('EinsteinBbb.pickle','wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(Bbb, f)
        with open('EinsteinBbb.pickle','rb') as f:
            EinsteinBbb_read = pickle.load(f)
        # TODO: Open 'EinsteinBbb.pickle' with write mode and dump Bbb so that it does not need to be recomputed
    return Bbb[(nl, ll, nu, lu)]
print(EinsteinBbb(1,2,3,4))
```

When I try for example `print(EinsteinBbb(2,1,2,0))` I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`
I feel like my code is very far from being right but any advice would be incredibly helpful!

**Edit:** Creating a minimal reproducible made the `TypeError` disappear, and I think it had to do with where the code was stored, but now I get `KeyError` for any key other than the one I ran the code with the first time.

Comment: Any further explanations? Pickle usage in your code looks like it should be. Where is the problem? Have you debugged it?
Errata : Here is error `pickle.dump('EinsteinBbb.pickle', f)`. Should be `pickle.dump(Bbb, f)` because i assume you want to save Bbb variable.

Comment: Right! I probably should've mentioned what goes wrong, well when I try for example `print(EinsteinBbb(2,1,2,0))` I get `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Exactly, because instead of saving `Bbb` you save string `'EinsteinBbb.pickle'` inside pickle file.

Comment: Ohhh so it should be `pickle.dump(Bbb[(nl, ll, nu, lu)], f)`?

Comment: @s.paszko Changing it to `pickle.dump(Bbb,f)` Is most definitely a correct step but the TypeError however, remains.

Comment: You need to `pickle.dump(Bbb, f)` if you want to save `Bbb`. Your code is currently pickling a string as @s.paszko pointed out.

Comment: @martineau I've done that now but still get the same error message, but I will keep the change,any other suggestions?

Comment: You haven't made that change in the current version of you code (which still has `pickle.dump('EinsteinBbb.pickle', f)`). As far as I can tell, the `Bbb` variable isn't defined anywhere either. Please provide a runnable [mre].

Comment: @martineau I have created a minimal reproducible, which solved the problem but created a new one, I've edited the question to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following does what you want (including all your TODOs as well as not producing a `KeyError` for keys not already in the `Bbb` dictionary). It uses exceptions to determine when it can initialize the dictionary from the existing pickled cache file, as well as when an attempt is being made to access a non-existent entry so an new entry for it gets added.

I put in number of print calls to enable you to see what it's doing.

**Tip:** Most of the time you should avoid using "bare" `except:` statements when handling exceptions because they can hide things you *would* probably like to allow to occur, like `SyntaxError`s or `SIGINT` keyboard (Ctrl + C) signals, and therefore would not want suppressed. In situations where you're not exactly sure what to expect, use `except Exception:` instead to avoid the problem of catching too much (because it won't include them).

```
import pickle


PICKLE_FILEPATH = 'EinsteinBbb.pickle'

# Load or create cache dictionary
try:
    with open(PICKLE_FILEPATH, 'rb') as f:
        Bbb = pickle.load(f)
    print('Bbb dictionary read from file.')
except Exception:
    print('Creating Bbb dictionary.')
    Bbb = dict()

def EinsteinBbb(nl, ll, nu, lu):
    try:
        return_value = Bbb[(nl, ll, nu, lu)]
        print(f'Using existing entry for ({nl}, {ll}, {nu}, {lu}) in Bbb.')
    except KeyError:
        print(f'Adding entry ({nl}, {ll}, {nu}, {lu}) to Bbb.')
        return_value = Bbb[(nl, ll, nu, lu)] = nl*ll*nu*lu
        # Overwrite pickle file with updated dictionary.
        with open(PICKLE_FILEPATH, 'wb') as f:
            pickle.dump(Bbb, f)

    return return_value

print(f'{EinsteinBbb(1,2,3,4)=}')
#print(f'{EinsteinBbb(2,3,4,5)=}')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm a little confused on what you did to solve the KeyError? Was it explicitily doing except KeyError that solved it?

Comment: Yes, the `except KeyError:` is how. I could have explicitly checked if the key was present or not before attempting to use it, which is referred to as  **LBYL** which stands for "Look before you leap", however I chose instead to use what's known as **EAFP** which stands for "It's easier to ask forgiveness than permission" because that approach is considered to be "more pythonic" (and is often shorter). See my answer to [Determine whether a key is present in a dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733992/determine-whether-a-key-is-present-in-a-dictionary).